# How to hide every comment in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

At my new job we have a pretty strange database, we have like 9 row of comment from every 10 row.

It's pretty annoying and really hard to understand what happen.

Near all comments are unnecessary, so I like to find a way to hide all of them, so I could actually read the code. I use Qt Creator.

I didn't found a solution yet, do someone have any idea?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are your blocks comment set using `//` or `/* ... */` ?

Comment: Both happens alot. :'(

Comment: Do you just want to hide its or you can remove its ?

Comment: it's the company policy that we should comment every letter we write, so i can't. For example there is a function `validate` with 1 parameter... it has a 4 row comment section, which write, that "it's validate the given parameter"... thank you Sherlock! :)

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing i know is that you can fold with `ctrl + >`. You'd need to manually collapse each block, though.

In only works for block comments, not multiline comments done with '//'.

Comment: There is a "toggle fold all", but it will just collapse all functions, the comments before the functions will still be there, and as soon as i uncollapse it, i will see tons of comments in the function still. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that on Qt Creator so far.

Parse the source code file to a new file, study the problem and try your solution on the clean file. After you are done, do the extra work of copy/paste the solution on the dirty (commented) file.